# Weird font in system windows

Tags: macos, font

Suddenly all the system windows have this weird font. I can't read nor understand what the system is asking me. How can I change it to normal fonts?

[image]

I'm using OS X Yosemite 10.10.3

Comment: There is a app in your Application folder called Font Book. Open it and under File tab  run restore standard fonts. If that fails report back here since then you have more serious problem, having something corrupting your Fonts.

Answer (score 3):

Open Font Book and choose File → Restore Standard Fonts…

If that doesn't work, restart in safe mode (hold the shift when you hear the boot chime).

Comment: This one worked for me. Everything is fine again. Don´t know why this happened. Thanks.